# async function not working in a module's callback

Tags: async-await

I am trying to chain a few functions but the one below is giving me issues.

The watermark module I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-watermark

Snippet of it working:

```
async function watermarkFile(filePaths){

    var waterMarkOptions = {
        'text' : 'blabla.com',
        'align' : 'ltr',
        'dstPath' : filePaths[1]
    }

    await watermark.embedWatermarkWithCb(filePaths[0], waterMarkOptions, function(err) {
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({error: err});
        } else{
            resizeImage(filePaths); //I want this one to be await but I can't as the function callback isn't async
        }
    });
};
```

Snippet of it erring:

```
async function watermarkFile(filePaths){

    var waterMarkOptions = {
        'text' : 'blabla.com',
        'align' : 'ltr',
        'dstPath' : filePaths[1]
    }

    await watermark.embedWatermarkWithCb(filePaths[0], waterMarkOptions, async function(err) {
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({error: err});
        } else{
            await resizeImage(filePaths);
        }
    });
};
```

The error I get is:

```
(node:11261) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Image-Watermark::embedWatermarkWithCb : Invalid arguments to method embedWatermarkWithCb
```

All I want to do it call **resizeImage** with await.

I am new to the async await syntactic sugar so I may be doing something obviously wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image-watermark` using [node-ratify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ratify) to check your callback is a function or not. And it returns false when the callback function is an async function, then it throws an error. [Read more](https://github.com/luthraG/image-watermark/blob/master/watermark.js#L219).

Now, have 2 options:

1. Convert `embedWatermarkWithCb` to a Promise function and call `resizeImage` after it finished (Recommended).

```
async function watermarkFile(filePaths) {
  var waterMarkOptions = {
    'text': 'blabla.com',
    'align': 'ltr',
    'dstPath': filePaths[1]
  }

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    watermark.embedWatermarkWithCb(filePaths[0], waterMarkOptions, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);

      }
      resolve()
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err });
  })
  await resizeImage(filePaths);
}
```

2. Using immediate function

```
function watermarkFile(filePaths) {
  var waterMarkOptions = {
    'text': 'blabla.com',
    'align': 'ltr',
    'dstPath': filePaths[1]
  };

  watermark.embedWatermarkWithCb(filePaths[0], waterMarkOptions, function (err) {
    (async () => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err });
      } else {
        await resizeImage(filePaths);
      }
    })();
  });
}
```

Comment: When I said I was new to async await, I was using Promises before - so thought maybe I was doing something wrong. It works like a charm - thanks for digging into it mate. Highly appreciated!